# Laravel dusk don't see text inside textarea

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

I want to test that if I type a word in textarea, then I should see the word inside the textarea.

```
/** @test */
public function type_a_word_should_see_a_word()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/test')
            ->keys('textarea', 'hello')
            ->with('textarea', function ($textarea) {
                $textarea->assertSee('hello');
            });
        });
}
```

The Assertion is fail, "Did not see expected text [hello] within element [body textarea].
Failed asserting that false is true."

But I can see the word "hello" from screenshot, is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `->assertValue($textarea,'hello')` rather than `->assertSee()` and I think the code should be like this:

```
public function type_a_word_should_see_a_word()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/test')
            ->keys('textarea', 'hello')
            ->assertValue('textarea','hello')
        });
}
```